# How to parse <first_value> aggregate in a group by statement [SNOWFLAKE] SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

How do you rewrite this code correctly in Snowflake?

```
select account_code, date,
       sum(box_revenue_recognition_amount) as box_revenue_recognition_amount
       , sum(case when box_flg = 1 then box_sku_quantity end) as box_sku_quantity
       , sum(box_revenue_recognition_refund_amount) as box_revenue_recognition_refund_amount
       , sum(box_discount_amount) as box_discount_amount
       , sum(box_shipping_amount) as box_shipping_amount
       , sum(box_cogs) as box_cogs
       , max(invoice_number) as invoice_number
       , max(order_number) as order_number
       , min(box_refund_date) as box_refund_date
       , first (case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_type end) as box_type
       , first (case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_order_season end) as box_order_season
       , first (case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_product_name end) as box_product_name
       , first (case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_coupon_code end) as box_coupon_code
       , first (case when order_season_rank = 1 then revenue_recognition_reason end) as revenue_recognition_reason

    from dedupe_sub_user_day
    group by account_code, date
```

I have tried to apply window rule has explained in [first_value Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) to no avail with the SQLCompilation Error: ... is not a valid group by expression

```
select account_code, date,
     first_value(case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_type end) over (order by box_type ) as box_type
     first_value(case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_order_season end) over (order by box_order_season ) as box_order_season,
     first_value(case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_product_name end) over (order by box_product_name ) as box_product_name,
     first_value(case when order_season_rank = 1 then box_coupon_code end) over (order by box_coupon_code ) as box_coupon_code,
     first_value(case when order_season_rank = 1 then revenue_recognition_reason end) over (order by revenue_recognition_reason ) as revenue_recognition_reason
     , sum(box_revenue_recognition_amount) as box_revenue_recognition_amount
     , sum(case when box_flg = 1 then box_sku_quantity end) as box_sku_quantity
     , sum(box_revenue_recognition_refund_amount) as box_revenue_recognition_refund_amount
     , sum(box_discount_amount) as box_discount_amount
     , sum(box_shipping_amount) as box_shipping_amount
     , sum(box_cogs) as box_cogs
     , max(invoice_number) as invoice_number
     , max(order_number) as order_number
     , min(box_refund_date) as box_refund_date
   
    from dedupe_sub_user_day
    group by 1,2
```

Comment: Perhaps doing the first_value's in a cte then the aggregation will help the optimiser a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First_value is not an aggregate function. But an window function, thus you get an error when you use it in relation to a GROUP BY. If you want to use it with a group up put an ANY_VALUE around it.

here is some data I will use below in a CTE:

```
with data(id, seq, val) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1, 10),
    (1, 2, 11),
    (1, 3, 12),
    (1, 4, 13),
    (2, 1, 20),
    (2, 2, 21),
    (2, 3, 22)
)
```

So to show FIRST_VALUE is a window function we can just use it

```
select *
    ,first_value(val)over(partition by id order by seq) as first_val
from data
```

| ID | SEQ | VAL | FIRST_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 11 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 | 10 |
| 1 | 4 | 13 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 21 | 20 |
| 2 | 3 | 22 | 20 |

So if we GROUP BY id, to avoid an error we have to wrap the FIRST_VALUE by an aggregate value, as given the are all equal, ANY_VALUE is a good pick, and it seems it needs to be in another layer of SQL:

```
select id
    ,count(*) as count
    ,any_value(first_val) as first_val
from (
    select *
        ,first_value(val)over(partition by id order by seq) as first_val
    from data
)
group by 1
order by 1;
```

ID  |COUNT  |FIRST_VAL
1   |4  |10
2   |3  |20

now MAX can be fun to use where used in relation to ROW_NUMBER() to pick the best value:

```
select id
    ,count(*) as count
    ,max(first_val) as first_val
from (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by id order by seq) as rn
        ,iff(rn=1, val, null) as first_val
    from data
)
group by 1
order by 1;
```

but this is almost more complex than the ANY_VALUE solution, but I feel the performance would be better, but if they have the same magnitude of performance, I would always choose readable to you and your team, over a smaller performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you've written your case statement, it leads me to believe that there is only one row with `order_season_rank = 1` when grouping by `account_code` and `date`.

If that is true, then you can use several of [Snowflake's aggregate functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-aggregation.html#list-of-functions-by-sub-category) and you will get what you want.  Rather than trying to get the *first* value, you could use `min`, `max`, `any_value`, `mode` (or really any aggregate function that will ignore nulls) to return the only non-null value in the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

- [first()](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_func_first.asp.html#gsc.tab=0) this link suggests first is only supported by MS ACCESS however you've tagged the question with MYSQL, Snowflake.  Could you confirm the DBMS's you are using?
- by moving the [first_value()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) function outside the aggregation it seems to work fine

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your suggestion works in Databricks Sparksql based on ANSI SQL  but fails in Snowflake cos the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) requires **first()** be used in a window function